# Raspberry Pi 3 boots to log screen but then turns off and again turn on

Tags: gpio, pi-3, sd-card

I was facing problems from previous days that some GPIOs don't work and then for some time Pi didn't start. Now it starts but just for 2-3 seconds. I see the debug log when generally Pi starts, but after that it goes off and again goes on. I want to know if the problem is Pi or SD card? As I have read SD card problem may do this too. But I was facing problem with Pi too.

And I have another Pi 3, so can I use the same SD card with that to check whether problem is Pi or SD card? Wouldn't that make any problem in my another Pi too?

Comment: The SD card shouldn't care which Pi it is on.  But I have a question for clarification.  Whenever I hear about this sort of issue I always check the power supply before anything else.  So, can you please clarify this question with a little more information, such as what kind of power supply you are using?

Comment: yes.  i am giving 5.02volt i have checked it many times but the weird thing is , when everything was right and i checked current it was about 0.70Amp and now i am getting abou 2amp. my another pi 3have 0.12amp when nothing else connected. nd i have read that the fuse f1 have 1.1amp limitation. so it should not go up from 1.1amp. so i think it suggest fuse is blown. bnut i tried to short it but that doesnt work too

Comment: If it is a Pi3 the fuse can handle a bit more than that.  You can pull 1.2-1.5 amps from the USB ports safely (that's a total, not per port).   I just tested one of mine with a flash card and ext WiFi adapter and it is taking .about .7 Amps.  
 If you blow that fuse it will not come and go - it will just be off.  Then you will have to feed power to it using the Vcc pin.  But back to troubleshooting:  What happens when you swap out the Pi with your other one and boot up on that SD card?  Does it act normal?  If so, then the problem is with the Pi.  If not, then the problem is with the SD card.

Comment: its booting with my other pi. but not with the prev one. how do i limit the current it fetches?

Comment: It will fetch whatever it needs, up to the limit of the protection circuit.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the comments where the SD card works fine in another Pi, the answer to your question is clearly that the problem is with the Pi.

It is always best that Raspberry Pis are operating on power supplies tested to work with them.

Since it is possible the power supply damaged the original Pi I would not recommend swapping them to find out whether that is the origin of the problem.